# Array of json objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I work with array of objects(json) in PHP?

```
$array = [{"field1":"valueX",
           "field2":"valueY"},
          {"field1":"valueW",
           "field2":"valueZ"}];

syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'
```

That array is a return of json_decode, and returned without single quote. Can I iterate with that format?

Comment: Use `json_decode`. `$array = json_decode( '[{"field1": ... ]' );`

Comment: Can I put single quote around array?

Comment: After your edit, I suspect you are in a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Above code has nothing returned from a `json_decode`: it is directly written. Can you explain your **real** situation? Also, original JSON string is generated by you? Last but not least: **all** strings are *returned* without wrapping quotes.

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k. You are right, because the original JSON string is generated by me. I have a android as a client and I fix the json generated by this app. Thanks for your help!